# Disable chrome extension according to url?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to disable the context menu (or the whole extension) unless its on twitter?
Ive tried content script setting but it doesnt work.

```
{
  "name": "TwitterHelper",
  "description": "Helps to make entering contests easier!",
  "version": "0.5",

  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus","tabs","activeTab"],

  "icons": {
    "16": "icon.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["myscript.js"]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },

  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

maybe query the tabs in the js but that would only not run the click event...
THanks!

Comment: Use `documentUrlPatterns` property when creating the context menu to filter only Twitter pages.

Comment: PERFECTION! thank you!